# Syrian citizen with Schengen Residence Permit traveling to Romania

Tags: visas, paperwork, romania

I have a friend and classmate who would like to visit me in Romania for a week during our autumn vacation but we are still unsure if he will be permitted entry or not.

On the website of the ministry of foreign affairs, it's clearly stated that holders of Schengen residence permits are allowed to stay for 90 days within a 180 day period, but someone from our school talked to the embassy and said that he does need a visa. However, we're not sure if that person mentioned the fact that my colleague has a type III residence permit issued by the Netherlands as well as a biometric passport for traveling purposes, so now we're a bit confused.

We only need some reassurance and the officials aren't very useful on this matter. Does my friend need a visa to travel to Romania for a week, or is the Schengen residence permit enough?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in Timatic, the database used by airlines:

> Visa required, **except** for Passengers with a residence permit
>   issued by Netherlands for a maximum stay of 90 days

So no, he does **not** need a visa - he just has to present his passport and residence permit card at the border.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm a bit late, but I can confirm that he indeed did not need a visa. In fact it was so unusual that even the border police needed clarification whether that travel document was valid to use in Romania or not. But they are known to not be very professional anyway...